# Set function error in Python3: list is unhashable type

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

When run the following code in a scratch file, everything works:

```
x = [1,1,1]
print(set(x))
> {1}
```

And yet when I run the following code

```
class MyClass(object):
   def __init__(self):
         self.mylist = []
   def train(self,vector):
         self.mylist.append(vector)
         self.mylist = list(set(self.mylist))
```

I get the error, `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`.

What's the problem here?

Comment: What type is `vector`?

Comment: You can only hash values that are immutable/unchanging (otherwise really weird things could happen). If `vector` is a list, it can't go inside a set. You'd probably want to use a `tuple` (immutable list) instead.

Comment: ah, that is it.  it is a list.  Is there a way to do what I am doing? for instance, I could pair the list with an integer value, since I am in a bounded, integer state space...

Comment: Got it, cool--thanks guys.

Comment: If you could clarify what you expect train to do, a fix could either be to change `vector` to a tuple or to use `.extend` rather than `.append`

Comment: Ah...extend sounds like the right thing to do.  Order absolutely does not matter.  And this thing should be doing whatever is O(1) for python lists...

Comment: Nevermind.  I guess in python, lists are stored backwards? Anyhow, .append is O(1).  https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you issue

```
x = [1,1,1]
set(x)
```

you are building a `set` from the elements in `x`, which is fine because the elements of `x` are of type `int` and therefore immutable.
However, `mylist` is a list of lists (because your `vector` objects are lists). The problem here is that the lists inside `mylist` are mutable and therefore cannot be hashed. That's why python refuses to build the `set`.

You can solve this issue by casting your `vector` lists to `tuple`. tuples are immutable and therefore Python has no problem with building a `set` from a list of `tuple` objects.

Demo:

```
>>> lst = [[1,2], [3,4]]
>>> set(lst)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
>>> set(map(tuple, lst))
set([(1, 2), (3, 4)])
```

Answer (score 3):

This is correct. List is unhashable because it's mutable. Use a tuple instead.